# What top level code is executed on import

Tags: python, google-style-guide

In Google python style guide it states *(towards the end for "Main")*

> "All code at the top level will be executed when the module is
>   imported"

I'm under the impression that top level code is any code in a `module(file)` that is indented at `0`.  So does that mean for example functions requiring arguments to be passed to them are executed? How is this possible or am I misunderstanding what top level code is and/or how things are being executed during import?

Here is a link for the [guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a module like:

```
a = 10

def some_function(a,b):
  do_something
```

on import assignment `a = 10` will be executed and a function some_function() only when you call it

Comment: The function is "executed" in the sense that executing a function definition defines the function, but the function is not called.

Comment: @Veedrac that was really helpful in clarifying the answer, we should be able to give pts for comments lol